# Syntax for using a dynamic array in a struct (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

```
struct FoodRec 
{
 string name; 
 int hsize; 
 string *healthy; 
};
```

Now suppose I want to create an array of the struct food rec and want to store data into the dynamic array inside, would the following syntax be appropriate;

```
Foodrec f[5];

int n=5;

f[0].healthy=new string[n];

f[0].healthy[0]="Fire";

f[1].healthy=new string[n+1];

f[1].healthy[0]="Water";
```

Comment: `std::vector<string>` may be more appropriate. (or at least `std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>`).

Comment: `std::vector<string>::push_back` could be helpful

edit: @Jarod42 was faster

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my main question is to find out whether the use of the dynamic array is appropriate if it's within a struct.

Comment: `std::vector` is a dynamic array. `string*` is a pointer which _may_ point to an array

Comment: I did that sometimes if I have a data structure with variable amount of measurement data e.g., but then with std datatypes that allow better organisation than a dynamic string array

Comment: Appropriate for what? Possible? Yes.

Comment: Else, you syntax is correct.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 yes the *concept* is appropriate, if you want a dynamic array you may certainly have one. No you should not implement it yourself - a `std::vector<std::string>` is a much better idea and provides efficiencies and correctness that will escape you otherwise.

Comment: When working with manual memory management in a struct/class, you should provide at least the copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor to avoid memory issues (rule of 3).  This is not needed when using a vector.

Comment: Since you use a raw array that is stored as a raw pointer when you don't really have to, no, this is not appropriate. This is C++, not C. Has not much to do with being in a struct, though.